# Ngnix Ingress Controller with for Long term support

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I see many different Nginx implementation.

1. I see some post saying stable/nginx-ingress`chart is deprecated, move to`ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress` chat.
2. This project https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases has two Nginx images `NGINX: 0.34.1` & `ingress-nginx-2.16.0` what is the difference between these two images.

Which Nignx Helm Chat to use for Long term support.

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ingress-nginx-2.x.x](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/ingress-nginx-2.16.0/charts/ingress-nginx) helm chart uses the [nginx-x.x.x container](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/ingress-nginx-2.16.0/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L6-L7). You don't normally need to reference the container image directly when using helm chart as that is set in the [default values](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/ingress-nginx-2.16.0/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L6-L7).

Helm itself moved a major version recently, from 2 -> 3 which caused a lot of changes to how helm repos are structured which is why you see the "deprecated" message in the old Helm 2 stable repo.

I don't believe the ingress-nginx project has an LTS release strategy. Just use a latest 2.X release or n-1 if you want to protect yourself from unexpected changes which get thrown in occasionally.

NGINX (the company) do provide their own alternative [NGINX kubernetes-ingress](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/) project if you are looking for commercial support.